# Is it possible for an encryption method to exist which is impossible to crack, even using quantum computers?

Tags: complexity-theory, cryptography

Quantum computers are known to be able to crack [in polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Polynomial_time) a broad range of cryptographic algorithms which were previously thought to be solvable only by resources increasing exponentially with the bit size of the key. An example for that is [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm).

But, as far I know, not all problems fall into this category. On [Making Hard Problems for Quantum Computers](https://physics.aps.org/synopsis-for/10.1103/PhysRevA.94.012320), we can read

> Researchers have developed a computer algorithm that doesn’t solve problems but instead creates them for the purpose of evaluating quantum computers.

Can we still expect **a new cryptographic algorithm which will be hard to crack using even a quantum computer**?
*For clarity: the question refers to specifically to the design of new algorithms*.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The title of your question asks for techniques that are impossible to break, to which the [One Time Pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) (OTP) is the correct answer, as pointed out in the other answers. The OTP is information-theoretically secure, which means that an adversaries computational abilities are inapplicable when it comes to finding the message.

However, despite being perfectly secure *in theory*, the OTP is of limited use in modern cryptography. It is extremely difficult [to use successfully *in practice*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15652/one-time-pad-why-is-it-useless-in-practice).

The important question really is:

> Can we still expect a new cryptographic algorithm which will be hard to crack using even a quantum computer?

### Asymmetric Cryptography

Asymmetric cryptography includes Public-Key Encryption (PKE), Digital Signatures, and Key Agreement schemes. These techniques are vital to solve the problems of key distribution and key management. Key distribution and key management are non-negligible problems, they are largely what prevent the OTP from being usable in practice. The internet as we know it today would not function without the ability to create a secured communications channel from an insecure communications channel, which is one of the features that asymmetric algorithms offer.

### Shor's algorithm

[Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) is useful for solving the problems of integer factorization and discrete logarithms. These two problems are what provide the basis for security of widely used schemes such as [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) and [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

NIST is [currently evaluating submissions for Post-Quantum algorithms](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/post-quantum-cryptography/round-1-submissions) - algorithms that are based on problems that are believed to be resistant to quantum computers. These problems include:

- [Lattice based problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice-based_cryptography)

  - [Shortest vector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problems#Shortest_vector_problem_(SVP)) (SVP)
  - [Closest vector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problems#Shortest_vector_problem_(SVP)) (CVP)
- [Multivariate equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_cryptography)

  - Multivariate polynomial equations
- [Code based schemes](http://hkumath.hku.hk/~ghan/WAM/Joachim.pdf)

  - Based on the hardness of decoding linear codes
- [Supersingular Isogeny Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_Isogeny_Key_Exchange) (SIDH)

It should be noted that classical algorithms for solving the above problems may *[exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm)*, it's just that the runtime/accuracy of these algorithms is prohibitive for solving large instances in practice. These problems don't appear to be solvable when given the [ability to solve the problem of order finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_phase_estimation_algorithm), which is what the quantum part of Shor's algorithm does.

### Symmetric Cryptography

[Grover's algorithm](http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post2644_grovers-quantum-search-algorithm) provides a quadratic speedup when searching through an unsorted list. This is effectively the problem brute-forcing a symmetric encryption key.

Working around Grover's algorithm is relatively easy compared to working around Shor's algorithm: [Simply double the size of your symmetric key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/23/29554). A 256-bit key offers 128-bits of resistance against brute force to an adversary that uses Grover's algorithm.

Grover's algorithm is also [usable against hash functions](https://dsprenkels.com/files/grover.pdf). The solution again is simple: Double the size of your hash output (and capacity if you are using a hash based on a [sponge construction](https://keccak.team/sponge_duplex.html)).

Comment: You make reference to [One time pad: why is it useless in practice?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15652/one-time-pad-why-is-it-useless-in-practice) but can't we use [BB84 quantum algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB84) to assure that the private key is shared securely?

Comment: @JanVdA Have you seen [this question and answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-is-quantum-cryptography-different-from-cryptography-used-nowadays/89#89) and [this one](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/142/162)? In theory under a certain set of assumptions, "yes". In practice, it's not so simple. For example, [IDQuantiques setup](https://bit.ly/2PnJl7g) does not benefit from the information-theoretic guarantee because they use the key shared by QKD for AES instead of a OTP. The reason for doing so is again practicality. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 There are theoretic techniques with certain assumptions that would allow you to share OTP keys without QKD: Securely meet in person with those you wish to communicate with at regular time intervals, and exchange key material on a physical medium (and assume it is destroyed properly after use). Theoretically, it works. In practice, it won't. Practicality is vital for adoption.

Answer (score 19):

I suppose there is a type of encryption that is not crackable using quantum computers: a [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) such as the [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher). This is a cipher with a keypad that has at least the length of the encoded string and will be used only once. This cipher is impossible to crack even with a quantum computer.

I will explain why:

Let's assume our plaintext is `ABCD`. The corresponding key could be `1234`. If you encode it then you get `XYZW`. Now you can use `1234` to get `ABCD` or `4678` to get `EFGH` what might be a valid sentence too.

So the problem is that nobody can decide whether you meant `ABCD` or `EFGH` without knowing your key.

The only reason this kind of encryption can be cracked is that the users are lazy and use a key twice. And then you can try to crack it. Other problems are, as @peterh stated that one-time-pads require a secret channel to be shared

Comment: It might also be worth noting that there is a [quantum analogue of the one-time pad](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~rdewolf/publ/qc/AMTW00.pdf).

Comment: What you describe is not the Vigenère cipher, it is running key variant of it. That is confusing.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, there are a lot of proposals for [Post-quantum cryptographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-quantum_cryptography) algorithms that provide the cryptographic primitives that we are used to (including asymmetric encryption with private and public keys).

Answer (score 6):

To follow up on Ella Rose's answer: most practical encryption schemes used today (e.g. Diffie-Hellman, RSA, elliptic curve, lattice-based) are centered around the difficulty of solving the [hidden subgroup problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_subgroup_problem) (HSP). However, the first three are centered around the HSP for *abelian* groups. The HSP for abelian groups can be efficiently solved by the [quantum Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform), which is implemented e.g. by Shor's algorithm. They are therefore vulnerable to attack by a quantum computer. Most lattice-based methods, on the other hand, revolve around the HSP for *dihedral* groups, which are nonabelian. Quantum computers are not believed to be able to efficiently solve the nonabelian HSP, so these algorithms should be able to implement post-quantum cryptography.