# Do we already know some problems, that would be hard to solve for quantum computers, and use them in cryptography?

Tags: complexity-theory, cryptography

I was wondering, whether there are any problems that we already know are difficult to solve for a quantum computer, and that we could potentially use in cryptography, just as we do now with e.g. the factorization of integers?

Comment: See this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-quantum_cryptography) on Post-quantum Cryptography, and see [this related question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/142/advantage-of-quantum-key-distribution-over-post-quantum-cryptography)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know a cipher with random key cannot be broken, however, in *classical realm* it is problematic to distribute the key without being eavesdropped. Probably physical exchange of the key would be necessary which impractical for digital communication.

**As to break random key cipher is not possible according to theory, it is not possible to do so even on a quantum computer. So there is a task difficult (or rather impossible) for a quantum computer which can be used in cryptography.**

But at the same time, quantum computers are used to implement the cipher. A *quantum realm* allows to create and distribute the random key and the same time being able to realize whether you were eavesdropped or not. See [BB84 protocol](http://eavesdropped) for more information how this is done.